# Этимология слов «бронировать» (= резервировать) и «бронь (брóня)»

Tags: этимология

Почему в русском языке то, что, например, в английском звучит как *to book* «зарезервировать, забронировать, заказать», выражается с помощью глагола «бронировать»? Аналогичный вопрос об англ. *booking* «резервирование» и рус. «бронь». Какова этимология этих слов в этом значении?

Comment: В русском языке то, что в английском звучит как «...забронировать», выражается... «бронировать»? ========= Разве это нелогично?

Answer (score 1):

Ну внутренняя семантика-то ясна. "Бронировать" - "укреплять", отсюда и до "закреплять" совсем недалеко.

С этимологией сложнее. Начнем с того, что брон**я** (укрепление) и бр**о**ня (закрепление) - это разные слова, наверняка родственные только на очень ранней стадии, а вот более поздняя этимология бр**о**ни не очень ясна. Возможно, польский сказался, возможно - наоборот, именно форма с ударным первым слогом - более древняя. 
Слово "бронь" (от бр**о**ня) считалась до недавнего времени просторечной формой, но сейчас её "повысили" до разговорной.

В целом, как версию, могу предположить распространение первого, "официального" значения слова "бр**о**ня" на менее "броневые" понятия вплоть до места в гостинице.

"Первое значение" - это "официальное закрепление за кем-либо или за чем-либо льготных прав на пользование чем-либо, получение чего-либо", в котором параллель с брон**ё**й (крепчайшей, государственной!) куда более явная.

https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F